# How do I provide the _NET_WM_STATE_FULLSCREEN hint with xcb?

Tags: fullscreen, xcb, ewmh

I'm trying to write a fullscreen application with xcb for my own edification and I'm having trouble with the above.  I've found a couple pieces of code that do this using Xlib, but none with xcb.  I've found the `xcb_ewmh_connection_t` structure and I'm tentatively using it like this:

```
xcb_connection_t *Connection = xcb_connect(NULL, NULL);
xcb_ewmh_connection_t EWMH;
xcb_intern_atom_cookie_t *EWMHCookie = xcb_ewmh_init_atoms(Connection, &EWMH);
```

and then using the atoms inside the structure with `EWMH._NET_WM_STATE`, etc.

Given this little background, how can I go about hinting the window manager that the window should be fullscreen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Examining `xcb_ewmh.h`, it looks to me like you also need to call

```
if(!xcb_ewmh_init_atoms_replies(&EWMH, EWMHCookie, NULL))
    /* handle errors */;
```

Once you've done that, the [`_NET_WM_STATE`](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html#id2578152) documentation should help for how to use this particular property.

See the [ICCCM](http://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/) section on [Client Properties](http://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/sec-4.html#s-4.1.2) for background on this technique of using properties to communicate to the window manager.

See the [ChangeProperty](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/xproto/x11protocol.html#requests%3aChangeProperty) request for how to set properties in general. That maps to the `xcb_change_property` function by the usual [protocol stub rules](http://xcb.freedesktop.org/ProtocolStubApi/).

I hope that's enough references to get you going!

Comment: Ah, thank you!  I'm sure actually getting the atoms after asking for them will help. :P  Sorry to be an xcb noob, but I'm having a bit of an issue changing the property itself.  Am I using this function incorrectly?
`xcb_change_property(Connection, XCB_PROP_MODE_REPLACE, WindowID, EWMH._NET_WM_STATE, XCB_ATOM, 32, 1, &(EWMH._NET_WM_STATE_FULLSCREEN));`

Comment: I figured it out!  Sorry about that.  By using XCB_ATOM_ATOM for the type instead of XCB_ATOM it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @cdbfoster I was having the same issue!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, whether `xcb_change_property` is the right way to go as the specification states:

> A Client wishing to change the state of a window MUST send a _NET_WM_STATE client message to the root window.

So far, I haven't seen any WM that ignores if you set it using `xcb_change_property`, though. Still, it might not work on other WMs.

---

> [...] MUST send [...] a client message

would translate to following code:

```
xcb_client_message_event_t  payload = 
{
    .response_type  = XCB_CLIENT_MESSAGE,
    .type           = atoms._NET_WM_STATE,
    .format         = 32,
    .window         = window_handle,
    .data           =
    {
        .data32[0]  = fullscreen
            ? atoms._NET_WM_STATE_ADD
            : atoms._NET_WM_STATE_REMOVE,
        .data32[1]  = atoms._NET_WM_STATE_FULLSCREEN,
        .data32[2]  = XCB_ATOM_NONE
    }
};

xcb_send_event(
    conn,
    1,
    window_handle,
    XCB_EVENT_MASK_SUBSTRUCTURE_REDIRECT
    | XCB_EVENT_MASK_SUBSTRUCTURE_NOTIFY,
    (const char*) &payload
);

xcb_flush(conn);
```

---

`atoms` is just a struct where I store atoms after querying their value.